# Ubuntu Mate 20.04 Panel Time Disappears

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, mate, indicator

Ubuntu Mate 20.04 Traditional Layout.

When the system starts the time and date appear in the panel. While the startup continues the time and date disappear. The panel remains with sound, wagon wheel, etc. Also happens with logout / login.

Tried switching to other layouts but the same appear and disappear happens.

Have tried resetting the indicator using dconf editor by changing to just time display with default.

Comment: See if you can download and install Dconf Configuration (I use this in Gnome and Mate is a continuation of Gnome). Then look in the Interface, Clock settings and see if this helps you.

Comment: Try resetting the panel with mate-panel --reset command

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but the OP says I have done both resetting the panel by trying different layouts and also tried using dconf to change the settings.